# Why RSA_generate_key uses uninitialized values (according to valgrind)

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, valgrind

I have been working on something that involves cryptography. I must admit that my knowledge in cryptography is very basic. So I decided to see what does the `RSA` structure contains after RSA key is generated by `RSA_generate_key` from `openssl` library. But I got a segmentation fault:

```
const unsigned long e = 3;
const int num = 3072;   
...
RSA *rsa_key = RSA_generate_key(num, e, NULL, NULL);
if (!rsa_key)
{
    printf("Failed to generate RSA key!\n");
    return RSA_ERROR_CODE;
}

printf("rsa->pad=0x%x\n", rsa_key->pad);
printf("rsa->version=0x%lx\n", rsa_key->version);
if (rsa_key->n)
{
    printf("rsa->n->top=0x%x\n", rsa_key->n->top); // HERE I got the seg fault
    ....
```

It looked very strange to me so I wrote a minimal code to test it with the [`valgrind tool`](http://valgrind.org/). Here is the code in C:

```
#include "openssl/rsa.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{       
    const unsigned long e = 3;   // the exponent, 3 in QVRSA
    const int num = 3072;   

    RSA *rsa_key = RSA_generate_key(num, e, NULL, NULL);

    if (rsa_key == NULL)
    {
        printf("RSA is invalid!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("rsa->pad=0x%x\n", rsa_key->pad);
    printf("rsa->version=0x%lx\n", rsa_key->version);
    if (rsa_key->n)
    {
        printf("rsa->n->top=0x%x\n", rsa_key->n->top);
    }

    RSA_free(rsa_key);
    rsa_key = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation line: *gcc rsa.c -lcrypto -g -O0 -o rsa*

This time there was no segmentation fault and the output was:

```
rsa->pad=0x0 
rsa->version=0x0 
rsa->n->top=0x30
```

**BUT** `valgrind` fired plenty of error messages:

```
==6916== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6916==    at 0x4DAEB37: BN_bin2bn (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DB1B62: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DB4471: BN_generate_prime_ex (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DC8763: RSA_generate_key_ex (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DCB763: RSA_generate_key (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x40072E: main (rsa.c:9)
==6916==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==6916==    at 0x4B23D6D: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==6916==    by 0x4D8936A: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DB1AD1: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DB4471: BN_generate_prime_ex (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DC8763: RSA_generate_key_ex (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DCB763: RSA_generate_key (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x40072E: main (rsa.c:9)

==6916== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6916==    at 0x4DB44D0: BN_generate_prime_ex (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DC8763: RSA_generate_key_ex (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DCB763: RSA_generate_key (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x40072E: main (rsa.c:9)
==6916==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==6916==    at 0x4B23D6D: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==6916==    by 0x4D8936A: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DB1AD1: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DB4471: BN_generate_prime_ex (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DC8763: RSA_generate_key_ex (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x4DCB763: RSA_generate_key (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
==6916==    by 0x40072E: main (rsa.c:9)
```

And many others with *Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)* title.

Why? Is there a known bug in openSSL or it is just a false alarm and my original segmentation fault is related to some hidden bugs in my original code?

I used:

- gcc v4.5.2
- valgrind v3.8.1
- OpenSSL 0.9.8a

Comment: Take a look on [openSSL FAQ](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG14) : section 14

Comment: @Missu Thanks. This might be the problem. I wonder why all my googling didn't find that link. However I have only the headers and the shared object of opensl. How ca I know if it was compiled with -DPURIFY?

Comment: Compile *openssl* from source with `-DPURIFY` flag if it's critical to you to debug a memory leak in a program using `openssl`. This is well known. Just download *openssl*'s source code and untar it, then cd into the directory and type this `./Configure --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/etc/ssl -shared -DPURIFY linux-(your arch)`. Also, why are you using such old versions?

Comment: @iharob Thank you. Believe me I didn't choose this version. This is the default openSSL version at the place where I work :)

Comment: Well they seem to use an old OS. Probably debian, no other distro uses such old software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenSSL is using some uninitialized variables to generate the random data to genearate the key. Then Valgrind will complain, so it is not false positive.

According to [openSSL FAQ](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG14), to get rid of it, compile with -DPURIFY.
However, you can debate whether it is a good idea to test a differently compiled binary than the production binary.

Comment: Please add also this link (provided by @Missu) to strengthen your answer: https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG14